# Why was Kamino erased from the Jedi Archives?

Tags: star-wars

What was the point to erase Kamino from the Jedi Archives? It was found just in time by Kenobi while he was following the trail of Jango Fett, something that would not be expected.

> It has to be used by the Republic and ultimately serve as a tool, through order 66, to raise the Empire.

So, why erase it if the whole point is to have the clone army used by the Republic?

Comment: I am resisting answering this question with "Tag and Bink"...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It doesn't really make it clear but the most likely reason is that Darth Sidious wanted it to remain hidden until the clone army had already been fully created.  Were it to be generally known beforehand that it existed and where, the clone army might never be allowed to reach maturity and the Separatists would have been far less likely to rebel if they knew that the Republic had an army within reach that could oppose them.  By removing it from the archive, it made detection less likely.  And even if someone learned the name, it would make it far harder for them to track it down.

And without the clone army and the war, Palpatine never rises to power as Emperor.

Comment: Has anybody ever thought that clone army was ridiculously small for an intergalactic war? From what I hear it was [less than 4mio units](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Grand_Army_of_the_Republic), compared e.g. to WW2 which had [100 mio military personnel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_War_II) and only covered parts of a single planet?

Comment: That always seemed really small to me as well to be conducting a galaxy-wide war.

Comment: Sorry to comment on here so late, but there's still something I don't get.  Kamino's clearly not visited very commonly, even the Jedi Librarian never heard of it.  And undoubtedly there are hundreds of billions stars in the galaxy, so it's pretty well hidden already if you don't know to go there. I'm not even that convinced that discovery would have been bad for Palpatine.  Obi-Wan found it and found out some of the details about what was going on and it didn't seem to set back Palpatine's plans one bit.  So why go to the trouble of deleting it?  He drew more attention to himself by doing so.